# How to make a Grouping By using Collectors

Tags: java, mongodb

I retrieve the data from a MongoDB database and I store them in a JSONObject after I add the JSONObject to a list each time in order to make the group by using Collectors (By date) I'm sure that the code of the group by is running correctly since I tested them in a simple example but the problem I have this display

```
 while (traficCursor.hasNext()) {
        try {
            DBObject next = traficCursor.next();
            wordsArray = next.get("Date").toString().split("\\s+");
            jsonObject.put("DateComplete",wordsArray[0]);
            jsonObject.put("Heure",wordsArray[1]);
            for (String mapKeyInfo : next.keySet()) {
                jsonObject.put(mapKeyInfo,next.get(mapKeyInfo));
            }
            data.add(jsonObject);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
try {
        Map<Object, List<JSONObject>> groupbydate = data.stream()
                .map(json -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(json.getString("Date"), json))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
        groupbydate.entrySet().forEach(gbd -> System.out.println(gbd.getValue()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[{"id_arc_trafic":"1","taux":"1360","DateComplete":"24/01/2018","_id":"5ce66598a4021f9e6224c699","debit":"61","Heure":"18:00","Date":"24/01/2018 18:00"},{"id_arc_trafic":"1","taux":"1360","DateComplete":"24/01/2018","_id":"5ce66598a4021f9e6224c699","debit":"61","Heure":"18:00","Date":"24/01/2018 18:00"},{"id_arc_trafic":"1","taux":"1360","DateComplete":"24/01/2018","_id":"5ce66598a4021f9e6224c699","debit":"61","Heure":"18:00","Date":"24/01/2018 18:00"}]
this is the last line of the JSONObject that repeats itself

this is what i want the grouping by Date which i display records by records grouping by Attribute Date

```
[{"id_arc_trafic":"1","taux":"100","DateComplete":"24/01/2018","_id":"5ce66598a4021f9e6224c699","debit":"250","Heure":"18:00","Date":"25/01/2018 18:00"}]
[{"id_arc_trafic":"1","taux":"1360","DateComplete":"25/01/2018","_id":"5ce66598a4021f9e6224c699","debit":"61","Heure":"18:00","Date":"25/01/2018 18:00"}]
[{"id_arc_trafic":"1","taux":"500","DateComplete":"27/01/2018","_id":"5ce66598a4021f9e6224c699","debit":"140","Heure":"18:00","Date":"27/01/2018 18:00"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonObject should get initialized inside the while loop:

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject();
```

If you don't do this, you'll update every entry of `data` with the latest inserted object's values

Comment: and the data.add(jsonObject); should be inside the loop or out?

Comment: inside, it's fine like that